# Ликвидация пересечений связей в ER диаграмме

Tags: база-данных

Есть такая вот диаграмма, необходимо ее реорганизовать так, чтобы ликвидировались пересечения связей. В ручную такое проделать у меня не получилось, может существуют какие-нибудь инструменты для автоматического выравнивания таблицы с ликвидированием пересечений? Или какая-нибудь литература, которая поможет мне понять, как это сделать? [image: ER-диаграмма]

Comment: Убейте меня... есть специализированные средства для разработки ER диаграмм. Например ERStudio Data Architect. Но большинство из них платные. И да - даже в них Вы не сможете избежать всех пересечений в 100% случаев.

Comment: Ну, про то, что есть специализированные средства я в курсе, это учебное задание задано в таком виде) Сам пользуюсь онлайн сервисами, пробовал разные, но ни один не облегчал жизнь. Судя по тому, что это учебное задание, решение данной проблемы должно существовать, но сколько вариантов я не пробовал, пересечений пока избежать не удалось.

Comment: где взять то что я сказал говорить не буду, сами догадайтесь )))). Пересечение связей между таблицами в ER схемах - это нормально, не всякая структура без них обойдется. Тем более накрученная. Алгоритмов расстановки в том софте что я сказал - штуки 3, но не факт, что обязательно поможет. Вполне нормально что придется "дорабатывать напильником", что также не гарантирует абсолютное отсутствие пересечений. Попробуйте, может справитесь.